# Crack when removing earphones

Tags: sound, laptop, soundcard

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Asus n76vz laptop. When I remove earphones, I hear a crack in the laptop speakers which is quite loud. If I mute the sound, the crack is audible, but at a lower level.

Is there a simple way to diagnose and solve this problem ? The sound seems to be fully functional aside from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem disappear, and I do not know why. Maybe because of a kernel update, or because I installed something particular.

Answer (score 2):

That "crack sound" you hear is when you plug off the connector is the contact in the plug socket, that bridges the gap between the left and the right audio signal (for a really short time). This ends in some kind of back coupling of the signal: the weird crack sound.

So this cannot be avoided through software, because it's a hardware related idiosyncrasy of the jack connector.

[image]

Comment: Well I do not want to troll or anything, but this problem was not present while Windows 7 was the OS of the machine, so I can safely assume that this is indeed software related.

Comment: Also the diagram you present is for a microphone, while I have problems with an output device. Did I misunderstood something ?

Comment: It's about the type of the connector. Microphone and speaker have the same. And the other thing is windows 7 probably tries to detect those flapping noises and filter them away. You will hear them also, but very quiet.

Comment: OK sorry, I forgot to say that I hear the cracking sound in the speakers ! I edit the question.